# TypeError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'HTMLSelectElement': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLOptionElement or HTMLOptGroupElement)'

Tags: javascript

Using the following code to get all the available microphones and update a selector with that list.

```
const audioInputSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioSource');

// Updates the select element with the provided set of cameras
function updateMicrophoneList(microphones) {
    audioInputSelect.innerHTML = '';
    microphones.map(microphone => {
        const microphoneOption = document.createElement('option');
        microphoneOption.label = microphone.label;
        microphoneOption.value = microphone.deviceId;
    }).forEach(microphoneOption => audioInputSelect.add(microphoneOption));
}


// Fetch an array of devices of a certain type
async function getConnectedDevices(type) {
    const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
    return devices.filter(device => device.kind === type)
}

getConnectedDevices('audioinput').then(microphonesList => updateMicrophoneList(microphonesList));
```

Getting the error:

```
audio_devices.js:11 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'HTMLSelectElement': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLOptionElement or HTMLOptGroupElement)'
    at audio_devices.js:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at updateMicrophoneList (audio_devices.js:11)
    at audio_devices.js:21
```

How can I force `document.createElement('option')` to create an element of the required type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "label" on an option and you need to `return` the option

```
audioInputSelect.innerHTML = '';
microphones.map(microphone => {
    const microphoneOption = document.createElement('option');
    microphoneOption.textContent  = microphone.label;
    microphoneOption.value = microphone.deviceId;
    return microphoneOption;
}).forEach(microphoneOption => audioInputSelect.add(microphoneOption));
```

or

```
audioInputSelect.innerHTML = '';
microphones.map(microphone => {
    const microphoneOption = document.createElement('option');
    microphoneOption.textContent  = microphone.label;
    microphoneOption.value = microphone.deviceId;
    audioInputSelect.add(microphoneOption);
})
```

But this is shorter and faster

```
audioInputSelect.innerHTML =  microphones
  .map(({deviceId, label }) => `<option value="${deviceId}">${label}</options>`)
  .join("");
```